# Tell github to use custom file to display as the project's README

Tags: github

Is there a way to tell github that the project's readme file is not `README.md` but `<project-name>.md`?

Answer (score 1):

[The GitHub documentation](https://help.github.com/articles/about-readmes/) states that GitHub will specifically display the contents of a file named `README.md` that is present in the root of your project or in the `.github` or `docs` subdirectories.

There doesn't appear to be an alternative here, though you could make your `README.md` file simply contain a link to another page of your choice.

Answer (score 1):

Create a directory called `.github` and add a `README.md` there, but not an ordinary file. Use a symlink to the file you want to be the readme.

```
 $ mkdir .github
 $ cd .github
 $ ln -s ../project-name.md ./README.md
 $ git add README.md
```